# How can I follow the steps on an article about translating from Web UI to Polymer?

Tags: dart, dart-webui, polymer

I tried to follow the steps on this [article](http://blog.dartwatch.com/2013/08/translating-web-ui-x-click-counter-to.html), but the sample app does not work.
Has Polymer.dart changed after the article publication?

What should I do to get the steps on the article to work properly?

Comment: Can you please be more specific. What do you mean "the sample app does not work" ?

Comment: Article author here - @Gero's answer seems to be correct.  What specific issues are you having?  (feel free to ping me off list, and I'll update this with an alternative solution if req'd).

Answer (score 1):

I just checked the example and it works for me.

1. Create new Web Application and copy paste code from here: https://gist.github.com/chrisbu/6220424
2. Rename all your 4 created files to match eachother name references.
3. In your pubspec.yaml you should add "polymer" package.